# How to verify file using rsa public key

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa, node-crypto

I base my work on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024428/6240756)

I'm trying to verify a file using a public key. Here is my code:

```
var hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
hash.setEncoding("hex");
var fd = fs.createReadStream("path/to/my/file");
fd.on("end", function() {
    hash.end();
    var fileHash = hash.read();    
    const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('keys/public_key.pem');
    const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
    const testSignature = verifier.verify(publicKey, fileSignature, 'base64');
    console.log("testSignature: \n" + testSignature);
    if (testSignature === fileHash)
        console.log("ok");
    else
        console.log("not ok");
});
fd.pipe(hash);
```

I don't know if this code is correct, but `testSignature` is equal to "false" when i printed it in the console. Why ?

```
testSignature:
false
```

The encrypted hash (the `fileSignature` variable) is correct. The base64 string is the same as I expect.

Any idea about what is wrong in my code ? Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the code that generates the signature:

```
var hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
hash.setEncoding("hex");
var fd = fs.createReadStream("path/to/file");
fd.on("end", function() {
    hash.end();
    var fileHash = hash.read();
    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('keys/private_key.pem');
    var signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
    signer.update(fileHash);
    fileSignature = signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
});
fd.pipe(hash);
```

Comment: Where do you use `openssl` here? (what's the tag for?)

Comment: I just reused the tags from the question I've mentioned

Comment: Actually I used openssl to create the keys. I've updated the tags

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: md5 and sha256 are different and incompatible hash algorithms. From what I can glean from the very poor documentation, you should pass the file contents (not the hash of the file contents) to the `verify.update()` method and it will do the hashing internal to the class. When the file is finished then you call the `verify.verify()` method.

Comment: @Heraldo v10.15.3

Comment: @JamesKPolk it's not what it's done in the answer i've mentionned. But I've changed the hash to `sha256` to try, same problem -> `false`

Comment: @iAmoric: I cannot test it myself so I cannot confirm. For reasons I can't fathom, the documentation says very little of substance. However, it would be a strange API to have an `update()` method that expects a hash of data rather than the data itself. Also, in any question like this, we must also see the code that generates the signature.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I've edited my question by adding the code that generates the signature

Comment: These edits change things a lot, and render my previous comments obsolete. One thing to be alert for is lack of symmetry in crypto operations. Notice how you call `update()` in the signature generation, but not in the signature verification? That's a clue that you're doing something wrong. `fileHash` is not used at all.

Comment: Yes I noticed it too, but my code is totally based on it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024428/6240756 where there is no update call in the veriffication and it seems to work correctly

Comment: That answer looks completely wrong to me. There are many completely wrong answers on stackoverflow that are accepted and highly rated. I'm not a javascript expert so you should definitely not take my word for it, but you should also not blindly accept an answer just because it is both accepted and highly rated.

Comment: I'm not saying that and I agree with you, according to the doc there should be a `verify.update()` but I don't understant what content i need to provide to this function. Also in my code the fileHash is compared  with testSignature. Both should be equal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193115/discussion-between-iamoric-and-james-k-polk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `path/to/my/file` is the file of which contents you need to verify, you have to provide its contents to `verifier.update()`. Try the following:

```
const input = fs.readFileSync('path/to/my/file'); // load data contents
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('keys/public_key.pem').toString(); // load the signature, as a string!
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verifier.update(input); // provide data contents to the verifier
const testSignature = verifier.verify(publicKey, fileSignature, 'base64');
console.log("testSignature: \n" + testSignature);
```

Also, make sure that `fileSignature` is a string value and not a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings). For some reason, which I am still trying to figure why, if you pass a Buffer object to [`verifier.verify`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_verify) it will not work:

```
const fileSignatureBuffer = fs.readFileSync('signature.sha256');
const fileSignatureString = fileSignatureBuffer.toString();
// load public key, create the verifier, provide data contents to verifier, etc.
const testSignature = verifier.verify(publicKey, fileSignatureBuffer); // false
const testSignature = verifier.verify(publicKey, fileSignatureString, 'base64'); // true
```

**EDIT:**
If you are using a hash as input to the signing step, then you have to pass the same hash in the verify step. Then code would look as follows:

```
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('keys/public_key.pem').toString(); // load the signature, as a string!
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verifier.update(fileSignature); // provide the file signature to the verifier
const testSignature = verifier.verify(publicKey, fileSignature, 'base64');
console.log("testSignature: \n" + testSignature);
```

Comment: I just tied it but i still have `false` as result . `fileSignature` is a string, not a buffer

Comment: I see that you are signing the file hash, not the input file content itself, so you have to provide the hash to `verify.update()` instead of the input file content.